# Plotting amplitude and phase spectrum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis

We are supposed to write a code that will help us plot the following signal and their amplitude and phase spectrum.

1. unit step
2. exponential
3. unit ramp
4. sinc
5. rectangular

I believe I can scrap the code for displaying these signal, but I am not sure how do I create their Amplitude and Phase spectrum. I googled how to plot the Amplitude and Phase spectrum of a signal, I even read the questions about it on this stack, but they always threw an error "*Index exceeds the number of array elements (1001).*"

Here is a code that I have written:

```
    clc;
    close all;
    clear('all');
    fs = 1000;
    t=0:0.00005:0.05;
    x1=sin(200* pi*t);
    % subplot(3,1,1);
    figure;
    plot(t, x1);
    % stem(t, y);
    xlabel('Time');
    ylabel('Amplitude');
    title('fig1:sine wave');
    
    Mag1= abs(fft(x1,2048));
    for j=1:1024
        f(j)=j*8000/(2*1024);
    end
    y1= angle(x1);
    figure;
    plot(f, Mag1(1:1024));
    xlabel('frequecy in Hz');
    ylabel('Magnitude');
    title('Magnitude spectrum of sine wave');
    figure;
    % subplot(3,1,2);
    plot(f, y1(1:1024));
    xlabel('Frequency'); 
    ylabel('Phase');
    title('Phase spectrum of sine wave');
    figure;
```

I started with this code, but it didn't work. After googling a bit, I came across this piece of code.

```
fs=500; %sampling frequency
T=0.2; %width of the rectangule pulse in seconds

t=-0.5:1/fs:0.5; %time base

x=rectpuls(t,T); %generating the square wave

plot(t,x,'k');
title(['Rectangular Pulse width=', num2str(T),'s']);
xlabel('Time(s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

L=length(x);
NFFT = 1024;
X = fftshift(fft(x,NFFT)); %FFT with FFTshift for both negative & positive frequencies
f = fs*(-NFFT/2:NFFT/2-1)/NFFT; %Frequency Vector

figure;
plot(f,abs(X)/(L),'r');
title('Magnitude of FFT');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude |X(f)|');

clearvars;
x = [ones(1,7) zeros(1,127-13) ones(1,6)];
subplot(3,1,1); plot(x,'k');
title('Rectangular Pulse'); xlabel('Sample#'); ylabel('Amplitude');

NFFT = 127;
X = fftshift(fft(x,NFFT)); %FFT with FFTshift for both negative & positive frequencies
f = (-NFFT/2:NFFT/2-1)/NFFT; %Frequency Vector

subplot(3,1,2); plot(f,abs(X),'r');
title('Magnitude Spectrum'); xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('|X(f)|');

subplot(3,1,3); plot(f,atan2(imag(X),real(X)),'r');
title('Phase Spectrum'); xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('\angle X(f)');
```

I don't really understand this code, after the amplitude spectrum part I was completely blacked out.

Comment: Your question is way too broad; you are essentially asking for a Matlab/Signals and systems course. I suggest starting from the basics on your own; grab a good book on each subject and start reading and solving the problems. You may ask specific questions here if you get stuck.

Comment: Is that so? Sorry about that. I just want to know how to perform Amplitude and Phase spectrum on signals, that's it.

Comment: You can use `freqz(input)` to plot the amplitude and phase response. Essentially this function is designed to calculate the frequency response of digital filters, but you can simply treat your signals as FIR filters.

Comment: @ZRHan By response do you mean their spectrum?

Comment: @Momobear [Frequency response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response) describes the output spectrum of a system while spectrum is a characteristic of a signal. In this case they are the same thing and both include amplitude part and phase part varying with frequency.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Dear admins, why is my question still closed? I removed all the extra chunk and extra questions.